# Counting a cell if another cell has certain strings

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Have a cell which will either have `W`, `L` or `BB` in it.
I want to add the cell in `O6` if the N6 cell contains any of the strings mentioned below what is the code for this?

below is what I currently have thought it to be.

```
=if(N6=("W"&&"L"&&"BB"),+O6)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the value in cell `O6` if cell `N6` equals "W", "L" or "BB", and get zero if cell `N6` does not equal one of those values, try this:

```
=O6 * regexmatch(N6, "^(W|L|BB)$")
```

The `regexmatch()` function will return a true/false value, but it gets automatically coerced into 1/0 when an arithmetic operator like `*` is applied.

Comment: I've now figured out i can just do =P5+if(N40="L",+O6)+if(N6="W",+O6)+if(N6="BB",+O6)
as im adding the number from a previous cell and this code runs down, is their a way to shorten this?

Comment: The formula you quote solves a problem different from what you describe in your question. Please edit the question accordingly. You can shorten the formula by using the pattern given in my answer above. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [The correct way to publicly share a Google test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219).